# Remove a piece of code after a number of execution?

Tags: c#, .net, jit

How can we remove a piece of code from a application after a number of execution? Let me give an example, right now, I have this application `SomeSoftware`, that takes backup of data every month or so. What it does is, that at the time of installation on client's machine (on deployment) it creates an entry in database about the date it was installed on, and then at each run it checks something like

```
var con = InitializeDB.StartConnection(); // start the connection
var cmd = con.CreateCommand();
var cmdOther = con.CreateCommand();
// check if its the first run of the software
#region onlyUsefulForFirstTime
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Count(*) FROM Misc WHERE ItemName='FirstRun'"
if (Int32.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString()) == 0)
    // it is the first run, add the entry
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Misc(ItemName, Val) VALUES('FirstRun'," +  DateTime.Now + ")";
else
#endregion
    // it is not the first run
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Val FROM Misc WHERE ItemName='LastRun'";
    cmdOther.CommandText = "SELECT Val FROM Misc WHERE ItemName='FirstRun'";
    // now after this, we compare the value of LastRun and the date in FirstRun, if it's more than a month, we take the steps to backup the database
```

what's happening currently is that at each start up of the application, it is executing the code inside region `onlyUsefulForFirstTime`, though its only useful for first time run. If client were to run this application 10 times in a day, it would be a total waste to keep letting this code execute. I know, I need to check somewhere if its first run or not, so to add the value, but after that its just waste. So, is there any way I could remove this code, and not exactly remove, but make the code in `onlyUsefulForFirstTime` not execute again, or something like that, well! you get the idea!

ps : I am not asking about other methods for backup or other strategy to backup, I know there are others, but that's not the question!

Comment: Is this something that couldn't be implemented in an installer?

Comment: If the code were in a separate DLL you could use lazy loading.  When you no longer want to find the code, delete (or rename) the DLL.  It hardly seems worth it for the example you've shown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Add a key to the Windows registry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5e7chcf.aspx), indicating that the code has already run.  Check this registry key on startup of your application.

Alternatively, you can use an [application setting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

```
if (Properties.Settings.Default.alreadyExecuted == false)
{
     // run one-time code.

     Properties.Settings.Default.alreadyExecuted = true;
     Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It's technically possible if you modify the CIL of your assembly and re-save it, but it's more trouble than its worth. Why can't you just use a local writeable INI file or even the Windows Registry to store the "last run" value so you can conditionally branch?

Note that changing your executable will break any strong-name on the assembly, and of course, Authenticode.

Furthermore, you can't do it in-memory due to DEP/NX which prevents writable memory pages from being executed.

EDIT:

By the way, your code has a bug in it.

`System.DateTime`'s implicit `ToString()` uses `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` to provide formatting information. In the US it will output "06/07/2012" for the 7th June but if you run the program in Europe it will output "07/06/2012" for the same date. Your SQL Server may expect dates in a certain format and suddenly your dates are wildly inaccurate. I strongly suggest you convert the DateTime value to an ISO-8601 format to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: +1 for DEP/NX and date part, didn't thought of that!
You said, "you can't do it in-memory due to DEP/NX which prevents writable memory pages from being executed." I don't know anything about that, writable memory pages being executed, and how .Net application would be affected by DEP or anything else in this regard. Can you provide any resource/website where I can read about this stuff?

Answer (score -1):

Don't [optimize](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization) unless there's a problem. No sooner than your profiler shows that the function is a bottleneck, start doing something about it.

Comment: Because the question-poster tries to do premature optimization?

Comment: Premature optimization is a term often used (and sometimes misused) to refer to optimizing for performance before it is needed.  You've used it here in an entirely different context.

Comment: I used it here correctly: "If client were to run this application 10 times in a day, it would be a total waste to keep letting this code execute."

Comment: Your answer would be a better one if you explained why you think this is "premature optimization."  In any case, what the OP really wants is to short-circuit the first-time code once it's already been executed, which is a perfectly legitimate use case.